# XAMPP Control Panel Error: MySQL Shutdown Unexpectedly,

Tags: xampp

I tried to start MySQL on the XAMPP control panel on my laptop, but I keep getting the error log message.

```
8:09:08 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
8:09:08 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
8:09:08 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
8:09:08 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
8:09:08 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
8:09:08 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
8:09:08 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

I already tried looking into similar issues on here but I think its different. I tried some of the solutions that worked for others but I still get the error message.

```
2019-09-03 20:13:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-09-03 20:13:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-09-03 20:13:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-09-03 20:13:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-09-03 20:13:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-09-03 20:13:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-09-03 20:13:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-09-03 20:13:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=49468
2019-09-03 20:13:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting a batch to recover 112 pages from redo log.
2019-09-03 20:13:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 14 pages from redo log.
2019-09-03 20:13:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-09-03 20:13:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-09-03 20:13:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-09-03 20:13:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp3\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-09-03 20:13:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp3\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-09-03 20:13:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-09-03 20:13:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 1603190; transaction id 9
2019-09-03 20:13:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp3\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-09-03 20:13:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Cannot open 'C:\xampp3\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory
2019-09-03 20:13:52 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-09-03 20:13:52 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I still get error messages after trying out some solutions. Is there any way that the Error can be resolved?